# How to exit a program properly when using Scalaz Futures and the timed function

Tags: scala, future, scalaz7

This works as expected:

```
object Planexecutor extends App {    
  import scalaz.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  val f = Future.apply(longComputation)
  val result = f.run
  println(result)
}
```

This does not:

```
object Planexecutor extends App {    
  import scalaz.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  val f = Future.apply(longComputation).timed(1.second)
  val result = f.run
  println(result)
}
```

In the first case, the application exits normally whereas in the second case it does not. However, both versions properly print out the result value.

Is this a bug or is there something I am not understanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the threadpool that `timed` is using. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/concurrent%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Fscalaz%2Fconcurrent%2FFuture.scala#L218-L219) you can see that it's using a default of `Strategy.DefaultTimeoutScheduler` which is just a generic java threadpool and it's threads aren't set to daemon status. The default threadpool of `Future.apply` does have daemon status on it's thread set so the JVM will shutdown properly. To fix this you can manually shutdown the thread pool after your code finishes:

```
  scalaz.concurrent.Strategy.DefaultTimeoutScheduler.shutdown()
```

or you could pass a different threadpool:

```
  val newTimeOutScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, new ThreadFactory {
    val defaultThreadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory()
    def newThread(r: Runnable) = {
      val t = defaultThreadFactory.newThread(r)
      t.setDaemon(true)
      t
    }
  })

  val f = Future.apply(longComputation).timed(1.second)(newTimeOutScheduler)
```

you can also manage this via implicits so you don't have to manually add this:

```
  implicit val newTimeOutScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, new ThreadFactory {
    val defaultThreadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory()
    def newThread(r: Runnable) = {
      val t = defaultThreadFactory.newThread(r)
      t.setDaemon(true)
      t
    }
  })

  val f = Future.apply(longComputation).timed(1.second)
```

**UPDATE:**
It's a pretty simple fix so I made a [pull request.](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/815)